# Parallel exceptions are being caught

Tags: asynchronous, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, async-await, c#-5.0

somehow my exceptions seem to being caught by method they are executing in. Here is the code to call the method. As you can see I create a cancellation token with a time out. I register a method to call when the cancellation token fires and then I start a new task. The cancellation token appears to be working OK. As does the registered method.

```
var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource(subscriber.TimeToExpire).Token;
cancellationToken.Register(() =>
{
    subscriber.Abort();
});
var task = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{                  
 subscriber.RunAsync((T)messagePacket.Body, cancellationToken);
 return true;
})
.ContinueWith(anticedant => 
{
    if (anticedant.IsCanceled)
    {
        Counter.Increment(12);
        Trace.WriteLine("Request was canceled");
    }

    if (anticedant.IsFaulted)
    {
        Counter.Increment(13);
        Trace.WriteLine("Request was canceled");
    }

    if (anticedant.IsCompleted)
    {
        Counter.Increment(14);
    }
```

The next piece of code is the method that seems to be not only throwing the excetion (expected behavior. but also catching the exception.

```
public async override Task<bool> ProcessAsync(Message input, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Random r = new Random();
    Thread.Sleep(r.Next(90, 110));
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    return await DoSomethingAsync(input);
}
```

The exception is being thrown by the cancellation token but according to intellitrace it is being caught at the end of the method. I have tried a number of different options including throwing my own exception, but no matter what the continuewith function always executes the IsComleted or ran to completion code.
Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: It's hard to understand what exactly is going on with your code when we don't see all of it. Could you create [a small, but complete sample that shows your problem](http://sscce.org/)? Also, what is the difference between `RunAsync()` and `ProcessAsync()`?

Comment: Sorry I missed the RunAsync / ProcessAsync when pulling my sample code out Run calls Process with a couple of synchronous methods before and after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `RunAsync` is the same as `ProcessAsync`.

> The exception is being thrown by the cancellation token but according to intellitrace it is being caught at the end of the method.

Yup. Any `async` method will catch its own exceptions and place them on its returned `Task`. This is by design.

> no matter what the continuewith function always executes the IsComleted or ran to completion code.

Well, let's take another look at the code:

```
var task = Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{                  
  subscriber.RunAsync((T)messagePacket.Body, cancellationToken);
  return true;
})
.ContinueWith(
```

Consider the lambda passed to `StartNew`: it calls `RunAsync`, it ignores the `Task` that it returns, and then it returns `true` (successfully). So the `Task` returned by `StartNew` will always return successfully. This is why the `ContinueWith` always executes for a successfully-completed task.

What you really want is to `await` the `Task` returned by `RunAsync`. So, something like this:

```
var task = Task.Run(async () =>
{                  
  await subscriber.RunAsync((T)messagePacket.Body, cancellationToken);
  return true;
})
.ContinueWith(
```

You're still ignoring the return value of `RunAsync` (the `bool` it returns is ignored), but you're not ignoring the `Task` itself (including cancellation/exception information).

P.S. I'm assuming there's a lot of code you're not showing us; using `StartNew`/`Run` to just kick off some async work and return a value is very expensive.

P.P.S. [Use `await Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep`](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what i was missing.